# Get Facebook app-scoped user id from global Facebook id, or username

Tags: facebook-graph-api-v2.0

If you have a Facebook, for instance Zuckerbergs user id '4', or username, 'zuck', how do you get the new app-scoped id with `Graph v2.0` using the app's access token?  Can't seem to find anything about this in the docs.

Comment: If you are trying to determine whether an id is app scoped, user ids fall in the range [(id < 2200000000 || (id >= 100000000000000 && id <= 100099999989999)](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-js-sdk/blob/deprecated/src/xfbml/helper.js#L37). App scoped user ids will fall outside of this range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically the answer given to the other-way-around question, 
[Get Facebook User ID from app-scoped User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23937916/618320)
.

Basically, easiest straight forward flow is a call to https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://facebook.com/[FBID/USERNAME]&access_token=[APP_ID]|[APP_SECRET]

Doing that for Zuckerberg, will give you the familiar

```
{
  "http://facebook.com/4":
  {
    "id": "4",
    "first_name": "Mark",
    "gender": "male",
    "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/zuck",
    "locale": "en_US",
    "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
    "username": "zuck"
  }
}
```

But, if that user had only logged in to your app for the first time after 30th May 2014 (the changeover date), he'd have something like...

```
{
  "http://facebook.com/4":
  {
    "id": "277123456789101",
    "first_name": "Mark",
    "gender": "male",
    "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/zuck",
    "locale": "en_US",
    "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
    "username": "zuck"
  }
}
```

Giving you the 277... app-scoped id for your app.

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't look like this works for 2.0/2.1 (at least not anymore)

Comment: I just successfully make this call using version 2.3 of the Facebook Graph API:

    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3?access_token=[KEY]%7C[SECRET]&ids=4

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment by @Raymond Yee, you have to provide `APP_ID`, `APP_SECRET` and `FACEBOOK_USER_ID` (note that this is the numeric id, not the username):

So it works with this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3?access_token=[APP_ID]%7C[APP_SECRET]&ids=[FACEBOOK_USER_ID]
```

Comment: You have to put user ID, not username!!! Replace FACEBOOK_USER_ID with the numeric id, not with username

Answer (score -2):

You also get real facebook id from app scoped user id.  Solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34450491/2181069