# OAuth - How to get Facebook user profile url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I don't know why I've got the different between the `id` from Facebook url and `ProviderKey` in the controller.

Here is my profile url: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100008491477935. So, my id is **100008491477935**

But, when I use that account to login, the `ProviderKey` is not the same:

`var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();`

`loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider` is **1488586148101087**

I can get the picture from this url: https://graph.facebook.com/1488586148101087/picture

But, I've got error message *Profile Unavailable* when trying to go to https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1488586148101087

The `id` is not correct (different from `ProviderKey`).

I wanna get user profile url by using `ProviderKey` like the `id`. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: I think the second URL might be wrong.  The two URLs (incorrect and correct) posted are identical.

Comment: @Coulton Sorry, I have edited the second url.

Answer (score 1):

With the upgrade from Facebook Graph API v1.0 to v2.0, Facebook is using "App-scoped User IDs", so you cannot see the "original" user ID inside your apps anymore.

Refer to this Post(Question) for detailed answer.

[Get Facebook User ID from app-scoped User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805866/get-facebook-user-id-from-app-scoped-user-id)

Good Luck

Comment: That mean: There is no way to get user profile url like `https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxx`, don't you?

Comment: As much as i know, you can get permitted user details from graph Api with app-scoped id but not complete profile in browser.

Comment: The `link` property of the user object will return a link of the form `https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/{app-scoped id here}/` that you can use, it will automatically redirect to the actual user profile.

Comment: This is not working anymore.