# Facebook: How to derive real id from the app scoped user id or vice versa

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a app scoped user id. Now, I wanted to find its real id but as I went some existing forums like [Get Facebook User ID from app-scoped User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805866/get-facebook-user-id-from-app-scoped-user-id) it appears that it is not possible to derive real id from app scoped user id.

But I see that it is possible via https://izitools.com/en/tool/get-facebook-id-from-scoped-id.

Is there any Graph API which can be used to derive real id from the app scoped user id? 
If it is not possible, we might need to derive app scoped user id from real id.

It seems there is some solution to derive the app scope user id from the real id but could not figure out the solution. Could someone sheds some light on it?

Comment: You of course can't. If you could there would be no reason to have app scoped ids from the beginning. And what would you use the real id for anyway?

Comment: Basically, we do a user profile query using the real user id already. We have inserted the records into the DB. Our app will do polling on user profile every few hours so we are trying to implemented the real time notification using the Graph API webhook. Facebook sends the app_scoped_user_id in the response whenever some changes occurred in the user profile.

Our business logic should treat these two ids as one otherwise it would treat them as two separate users.

Comment: Just use the app scoped user id. You should treat them as different users. If you get two different app scoped user ids from different apps you can use the business mapping api to get which app scoped user ids are the same

Comment: _“Basically, we do a user profile query using the real user id already”_ – how? Where are you getting those ids from in the first place? Your app should only use the ids it gets from the API. If you feed ids from other external sources into your database, then you are doing it wrong to begin with.

Comment: Yes. Your are right. Initially, we were investigating from the Graph Explorer tool from the browser where we see the global id and we were a kind of confused. Actually, we only have to deal with the app_scoped user id which we get from the from App. Thanks for the clarification.