# How to get Facebook real user id from app scoped id

Tags: php, facebook, api

I've created an app for authorization users via Facebook, but not I need to get real ids for those users to be able to open their pages in the browser.
Is there any way to get current user page id by id which I've already received via Facebook api (app scoped id)?

I've trid this [example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/psid-api/) but an error occurs: `This method must be called with a Page Access Token`

I've already passed access token. May be `access token` and `page access token` are different thing, idk (poor docs).

Also `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/pages_id_mapping` (pages_id_mapping ) method doesn't work for `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer`.

I've also tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23937916/5246900) but it also doesn't work. It just returns exactly the same ids which have been passed.

[This](https://inkplant.com/code/facebook-app-scoped-user-id) is broken too.

I can't believe that there is no way to get real user ids from app scoped ids..
I need to get user links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook no longer, under any circumstances, makes the real Facebook ID for a user available via the API.

If you request (and are approved for) the `user_link` permission, `https://www.facebook.com/<app scoped ID>` URLs will be enabled. You are still not permitted to attempt to translate these links into the underlying ID, but you can use them in your UI or to visit a user's page.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-user_link

Comment: Thank you! I've send request for the app approval to get `user_link` permission.