# Laravel socialite login: different facebook apps

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I have integrated the Laravel login with Socialite and Facebook authentication.
I have configured the client id (the FB app id) and client secret(the FB app secret) into the config/service.php file.
All works fine but now I need to authenticate users from different Facebook apps (each with a different app id)
Is it possibile or should I have one Laravel app fore every Facebook apps ?

Comment: can you check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087051/facebook-api-different-user-ids-for-each-app

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to create a custom socialite provider. You can use the `buildProvider`
method to create another Facebook provider with a custom name of your choice and pass the client id and client secret of the second Facebook app to it:

```
buildProvider(FacebookProvider::class, $config);
```